# He Skips Without Asking Me the Question I Want To Ask

Tags: python-3.x

```
class validation():
    confirmation = input("Your information is as above, do you confirm?: E/H: ")
    if confirmation == "E":
        print("You can continue.")
    else:
        wrong_information = input("Which information is wrong: ")
        if wrong_information == name:
            print(input("Enter again: "))
        elif wronglis_information == surname:
            print(input("Enter again: "))
        elif wrong_information == address:
            print(input("Enter again: "))
        elif wronglis_information == il_ilce:
            print(input("Enter again: "))
        elif wronglis_information == population:
            print(input("Enter again: "))
        elif wrong_information == age:
            print(input("Enter again: "))
        elif yanlis_bilgi == phone_number:
            print(input("Enter again: "))
        else:
            print("You have not entered any information or the information you have entered is invalid...")
```

here I wanted to write a place where the user can say which information is wrong if the information is incorrect, and correct the value again, but my application runs the else: block without bringing me the "Enter again" information and continues to run the codes in the rest of the application, I did not understand the error I made here, the application ignores my code

Comment: Please correct the typos in your code (`wronglis_information`, `yanlis_bilgi`)

Comment: Don't you mean `if wrong_information == "name":` instead? And the same with all the other `elif` statements?

Comment: presents the information entered by the user to the user and asks the user for the information he entered incorrectly if there is a mistake, and asks him to rewrite the information according to the selected value, wrogns informantion I gave such a name to keep in my mind